# Calendar Themes

Tags: 7, theming, datetime

Are there any themes for the [Calendar module](http://drupal.org/project/calendar)? The out-of-the-box theme is not great. It be nice to find a new base theme without rolling my own.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any contributed themes that specifically cater to calendars. However, there are several sites that provide themes that are more likely to have considered Calendar module:

- [Fusion Drupal Themes](http://fusiondrupalthemes.com)
- [Adaptive Themes](http://adaptivethemes.com)
- [Omega Framework Group](http://groups.drupal.org/omega-framework)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) module; I think it looks nice.